# Configure MetalLB with NginxIngress to accept request from the Internet

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

We have a Minikube deployment on one VM on Bare Metal Cloud (OVH Cloud).

- Kubernetes version: v1.28.3
- Installation method: Minikube
- Host OS: Debian 10
- CRI and version: docker://24.0.7

We have deployed Nginx Ingress and MetalLB but cannot find a way to connect to the cluster from the outside (the public IP of the server). What we want to do is have a single entry point to the cluster listening on :80 and :443 and then distribute the request to the target service inside the cluster.

If we try to internally communicate to the web app (*with curl*) it gives us a response, but no way to get the same from the internet

Possible duplicates of (I've seen them but seems like nothing works for us):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223566/adding-public-ip-to-nginx-ingress-controller-with-metallb
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031505/metallb-with-nginx-ingress-controller-on-minkube-keeps-resetting-external-ip-for
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099703/metallb-external-ip-to-internet

Please bear in mind that I a newbie in Kubernetes.

Basically we followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8bxtsWe9qw)

Nginx Ingress deployed with Helm

```
helm install nginx-ingress oci://ghcr.io/nginxinc/charts/nginx-ingress --version 0.17.1 --namespace nginx-ingress
```

MetalLB deployed with MANIFEST

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.9/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
```

IpAddressPool:

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.XXX.XX.XX-192.XXX.XX.XX
```

For the addresses we've tried with:

- minikube internal IP range between 10 IPs
- We've tried also with a single ip with <minikube_internal_IP>/32
- We've tried also with a single ip with <SERVER_PUBLIC_IP>/32

L2Advertisement

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: homelab-l2
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - first-pool
```

A simple APP Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: web-app
  name: web-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: web-app
        command: 
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - "echo 'welcome to my web app!' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      dnsConfig:
            options:
              - name: ndots
                value: "2"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: web-app
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: web-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Ingress for the app:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: web-app.home-k8s.lab
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-app
            port:
              number: 80
```